# boost::multi_index index by function call with parameter(s)

Tags: c++, boost, function, boost-multi-array

I'm trying to make a boost::multi_index container that uses member functions w/ parameters as keys.

```
class Data {
public:
   std::string get(const std::string & _attr) { return _internals_fetch_data(_attr); }

/*
   assume some implementation for storing data in some structure(s)
*/
};
```

Suppose I have a *rectangular* list of these data items that I want to multiple indicies over. *rectangular* means all items in list have the same attributes via get()

The boost::multi_index declaration is something like

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  Data,
  indexed_by<
   ordered_unique<
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(Data,String,get)
   >
  >
> my_container;
```

Except that *BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUNCT()* does not have these features. 
Composite keys still work with member variables.

How do I get around this ?
It doesn't look like I can give ordered_unique<> a boost::function1

EDIT:

After some thought, here is the gist of what I'm trying to do.

boost::multi_index determines it's indexing features during compile time. How do I circumvent these features and use run-time determined indexes ?

Answer (score 2):

What do you suppose to pass as argument to function? What is `const std::string & _attr`?

Anyway, `BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN` is just a macro for `const_mem_fun` functor. You could write your own functor `const_mem_fun1`. But I have no idea how you going to use it. Implementation of `const_mem_fun` receives object by reference (or wrapper, e.g. `shared_ptr`) and then it calls member function with no arguments.

`boost::multi_index::indexed_by` expects type, not an object, as well as `ordered_unique` expects type. That's why you cannot write `const_mem_fun1<Data, std::string, &Data::get>("string")`. Why do you cannot use function `get` with no parameters and create special string field in `Data` struct?

```
struct Data {
  std::string _attr;
public:
  std::string get() const { return _internals_fetch_data(_attr); }
};
```

Comment: That's the problem. Doesn't look like I can use a _const_mem_fun1_ here.

Comment: How are you suppose to pass argument? Something like `ordered_unique< const_mem_fun1<Data, std::string, &Data::get>( "string" ) >` ?

Comment: Maybe ( "string" ) can be a struct/wrapper as another parameter.